# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue on xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, ipa, signing

When I tried to make an IPA out of my Xcode project (out of my Unity project), this error appeared and I don't know why:

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue

The project runs without any problems directly in mobile, and we tried the bundle identifier on other projects, it works. We tried rebuilding the Unity project from other PCs, this project has the same error. We can't make an IPA out of the archive.

Is there someone who knows where to locate the issue and how do we fix it ?
Thank you in advance !

[image: xcode error when I want to IPA this iOS project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! This solution worked, if someone is in the same case. https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-build-failing-fccore-bundle-has-conflicting-provisioning-settings-xcode-9-2-automatic-signi.520730/